# Export Shapely objects to DXF file

Tags: python, dxf, shapely, fiona

Using `shapely` package for **Python** how to export the resulting shapely objects such as `buffer` to a `DXF` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/shapely/) doesn't directly support exporting to DXF - it supports export to Well Known Text (WKT), Well Known Binary (WKB), Numpy arrays and [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) objects ([interoperation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130216020825/http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#interoperation) from the Shapely manual). As such you need a package that can transform from one of these formats to DXF.

I'd suggest [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) as the way to go for my money. The easiest method would be to simply export your shapely geometries to a GeoJSON file through Python using [`shapely.geometry.mapping(obj)`](https://web.archive.org/web/20130216020825/http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#shapely.geometry.mapping), e.g.

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import json
open("buffer.geojson", "wb").write(json.dumps(mapping(buffer_obj)))
```

Then simply use the [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility to transform the GeoJSON to a DXF file, e.g.

```
ogr2ogr -f DXF buffer.dxf buffer.geojson
```

Then, if you're keen you can look up the [GDAL/OGR Python bindings](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython) and do it within a single script. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. You gave many ideas which are very useful. I would like to try OGR through Python. This a good answer.

Comment: As explained in http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7744/390 there's a mismatch between the GeoJSON and DXF formats. Looks like you'll want to have a DXF template into which to stuff your lines.

Comment: Just to mention in execution of the provided code an error come up: "write requires string/buffer". So I changed it as: `write(str(mapping(buffer_obj)))` and it is OK now. I use Python 2.72 BTW.

Comment: and I also had to replace `()` with `[]` in the produced GeoJSON file to bypass another error caused using `ogr2ogr.exe`. Those may be changes in software or I'm missing something obvious! Anyway, with these two tricks it produced a DXF file successfully.

Comment: However `DXF` file may have some issues since I could not open it by different software such as LibreCAD, SketchUp etc.

Comment: @Developer Sorry about the mistake in the code - I've updated it with a reference to the Python [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) library to dump the mapping. Sorry that the DXF doesn't work though. Are there any other formats that OGR supports and that you can open in your CAD software (DGN maybe? Maybe shapefiles at a stretch?)

Comment: @om_henners Unfortunately only DXF and [GDS](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/gds) files are importable!

Answer (score 10):

BTW, if you appreciate Shapely, you may also appreciate [Fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona). The Fiona example in https://gist.github.com/1886782 could be adapted to convert a shapefile to DXF.

```
with fiona.collection("file.shp", "r") as source:

    with fiona.collection(
            "file.dxf",
            "w",
            driver="DXF",
            schema=source.schema,
            ) as sink:

        # Do whatever you like to records
        results = some_function(source)

        sink.writerecords(results)
```

It coughs up a lot of warnings about mismatch between GIS simple feature and DXF data models but does write a file of entities.

Comment: Thanks for introducing `Fiona` and also thanks for your interesting package `Shapely`. You are surely doing good job.

Comment: @sgillies That's awesome. If you need any further contributors please give me a shout! Also, any plans for GDAL?

Comment: BTW is there any pre-compiled for windows (Python 2.72) release of `Fiona`?

Comment: @Developer: Not till 1.0.

Comment: Thank you \o/ helpme this script

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Geopandas and Fiona Libraries
Here is the code to read a file using Geopandas and export it as a DXF File.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import fiona


#Read file using geopandas
x = gpd.read_file(filename with path)

#Save as DXF
x.geometry.to_file(output file name, driver="DXF")
```

Also, check the answer in the below link.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/377412/160313

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays new ways came along, thanks to the `__geo_interface__` interface standard and the [ezdxf](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

A sample code could be below were `shapes` holds your e.g. MultiPolygon

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import ezdxf
import ezdxf.addons.geo

doc = ezdxf.new()
geoproxy = ezdxf.addons.geo.GeoProxy.parse(mapping(shapes))

msp = doc.modelspace()

# Use LWPOLYLINE instead of hatch.
for entity in geoproxy.to_dxf_entities(polygon=2): 
    msp.add_entity(entity)

doc.saveas("test.dxf")
```