# Converting GeoDataFrame to DXF using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, dxf

I have ten geodataframe;
I would like to export each one of them to DXF:

```
geodataframes= [gdf1,gfd2,gdf2]
for geodataframe in geodataframes:
    #geodataframe to dxf
```

it would be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoPandas supports `dxf`. You just have to keep in mind that dxf can hold only geometry, not attributes, which means that you have to save GeoSeries, not GeoDataFrame.

```py
geodataframes = [gdf1, gfd2, gdf3]
for i, geodataframe in enumerate(geodataframes):
    geodataframe.geometry.to_file(f'file_{i}.dxf', driver='DXF')
```